# Microsoft Access DateDiff + Difference in time if end time is next day

Tags: date, ms-access, datediff, duration

I have a table with records, where each record has a date column, then a start time column and end time column.

I am trying to do a datediff to get the duration in hours from start to end date with DateDiff('s',[Start Date[,[End Date])/3600.

This works perfectly for End dates that are on same day as date column, but sometimes the end date would be the next day like 12:45 AM. The date diff will give me a large negative number, how do I let it know its next day?

I dont own the data, so not much I can do with the table

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
DateDiff('s',[Start Date],DateAdd('d',IIF([End date]<[Start Date],1,0),[End Date]))/3600
```

Comment: Excellent! Thank you

Comment: I have a new angle that I have to do with this. For each row that has a start and end time and a date field, I need to be able to get all total hours within a duration, like 24 hours. And if the start date is before the start of the 24 hours, then just the part of the window at 24 hours. For example:) date is 4/23/2018, start time is 2:30 PM end time is 4:00 PM. Query is run at 4/24/2018 3:00 PM, if this is the only record, need total hours to show 1 (4/23/2018/ 3:00 - 4:00) Also need the same 'next day' logic as mentioned in original post. Do I contactenate the date/time fields?

Answer (score 0):

It can be done with pure math:

```
TotalHours = TimeValue(CDate([End Date] - [Start Date] + 1)) * 24
```